# How can I display my comment form on the post detail page Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

So basically at the moment, if users want to add a comment to a post on my site, it takes them to another page with the form on it. However, I want the comment form to be on the actual Post Detail page, so users don't have to go to another page to comment.

So far I have tried adding some context things and changed the url for the comment form's location to `post_detail.html`, and put the `comment_form.html`'s code there, however this did not work.

Here are the relevant `views.py`
The `add_comment_to_post` view

```py
@login_required(login_url='/mainapp/user_login/')
def add_comment_to_post(request,pk):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post,pk=pk)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CommentForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            comment = form.save(commit=False)
            comment.post = post
            comment.author = request.user # add this line
            comment.save()
            return redirect('mainapp:post_detail',pk=post.pk)
            # remove `def form_valid`
    else:
        form = CommentForm()
    return render(request,'mainapp/comment_form.html',{'form':form})
```

Here is the `PostDetailView` view.

```py
class PostDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Post
```

Here is the `comment_form.html` code

```html
<form class="post-form" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <button type="submit" class="submitbtn">Comment</button>
</form>
```

And here is the relevant `urls.py` files

```py
path('post/<int:pk>/comment/', views.add_comment_to_post, name='add_comment_to_post'),

path('post/<int:pk>', views.PostDetailView.as_view(), name='post_detail'),
```

So at the moment, when doing my solutions I thought would work, I added the comment_form.html's code into the post_detail.html document, however it only showed the `Comment` html button. How am I able to have the CommentForm on the same page as the post detail page?

Thanks for any help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that when Django is rendering the `PostDetailView`, the `context` dict doesn't have the `form` item (the `form` item is only available at your `add_comment_to_post` view, since Django template engine cannot find the `form` item from `context` dict, it did not render anything.

What you need to do is to change your `PostDetailView` and to inject the `CommentForm` into the `PostDetailView`'s context. Here is one way to do it:

```py
class PostDetailView(DetailView):
        model = Post

        def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
            context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
            context['form'] = CommentForm() # Inject CommentForm
            return context
```

What you have done is essentially overwriting the default `get_context_data`, and inject that `CommentForm()` of yours as part of the `context`, and then render it

Comment: This worked up until the point of commenting. When I pressed the comment button, it brought me to a page saying ```This page isn't working```.
Hey would I be able to fix this? Do I need to change anything in the urls.py file?

Comment: I just added an action=" " to the form and it was all good
thanks man for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

```
class PostDetailView(DetailView):
        model = Post

        def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
            context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
            context['comment_form'] = YourModelFormForComment()  # Your comment form
            return context
```

In template

```
{{comment_form.as_p}}
```